# How do I remove any images and place a table at the position where the image is?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

How do I remove image(s) and place a table(s) of 'n' rows at the position where the image was? May be all images removed

```
 var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
    var images = body.getImages();
    var childIndex = body.getChildIndex(images[0].getParent());

 var cells = [
   ['Some'],
   ['Row 2, Cell 1']
 ];
 var tab = body.insertTable(childIndex, cells);
```

Comment: Does your script succeed in replacing the first image? Then all you need to do is to add a loop over the array `images`. What is 'n', by the way?

Comment: n means all the images (or else first n number of images like as a user  parameter), I am succeeded but it will not replace the image if it is between the paragraph. How do I replace images with table at the position where the image was?

Comment: If you are still looking for the solution, for example, is this thread useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53429094/replace-image-with-table-in-google-doc/53473448#53473448

Answer (score 0):

Reading through the [document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet), `insertImage()` is the only function that can be related to images. Updating or even deleting is not yet possible.

You can follow the existing [Feature Request -- Ability to delete images](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=64) to be updated about the details of this feature request.

Hope this helps.